# Blazor Web Assembly Components update ad custom object passing

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-client-side

Please consider this scenario:

I have one page that holds
**Three components:**

- InputComponent
- ActivityListComponent
- SummaryComponents

The first component includes a form that takes a URL as an input.

When the form is submitted, the application takes the content from this URL(JSON) and creates a List.

The second component is supposed to display the results of this custom object that contains a List within a form including a checkbox for each item allowing the user to deselect the items that are not required.

When the user is ready and clicks submit I would then parse the results and produce an output file.

The third component produces a summary of the results.

I am struggling to see how to change the visibility of ActivityListComponent and also pass a custom object from the code when the user clicks submit.

Basic question is:

How do I control visibility of a component as well as passing in a custom object?

Comment: You pass objects to components using Parameters. As far as controlling visibility of a component, you have several options. You can use code to conditionally write a style attribute with "display: none;" or you can wrap the component in an @if() {} block. It all depends on the effect you are trying to achieve. My advice is to learn a bit more about Blazor and then see if you can come back with more specific questions showing code that you've tried and explaining the challenges you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

I used Blazor events in the end.

```
// Child Object
public List<Cat> Cats { get; set; }
[Parameter] public EventCallback<List<Cat>> NewCatList { get; set; }

// Somewhere in the code I trigger the event
await NewCatList.InvokeAsync();

// Parent Object 
<InputFormComponent NewCatList="@Method" />

@Code {
    public void Method(List<Cat> Cats)
    {
        // Some code
    }
}
```

This was more of an issue because I was using @bind-value instead of @bind-Value in a child component and the error was not picked up or handled correctly.

Took me a short while to figure this out.

Great lessons learnt though :)